# How do I determine the ratio of warrants required to acquire common stock?

Tags: warrants

Is a warrants exercise price the same as the strike price?  How do I determine the ratio of warrants required to acquire common stock?

Answer (score 2):

Warrants are effectively long term options except that you buy and short them rather than buy and write them, as with options.

The price at which you can buy the underlying is called  the exercise price or strike price.

To determine if the warrants are 1:100 some other ratio, you can read the prospectus or you can do some Googling and find a quote site that lists the warrant to stock ratio.  I have seen them in my travels but I don't have a link for you.